# Get information from CIA World FactBook with REST / SOAP / API?

Tags: javascript, php, api, rest, soap

I'm looking for another way to get information from the CIA World FactBook instead of downloading a huge package of datas.
Maybe the CIA will only collect data. :-)

I found an old JAVA package to retrieve informations but I like a more modern way with REST or maybe an API. 
Something to solve with JavaScript and/or PHP or ASP.
I can't believe that this not exist.

Maybe someone knows a link or way that Google can't find. :-)

Or maybe someone knows a trusted site where I can find the names of all countries, their populations and languages.

Comment: http://data.worldbank.org/developers/api-overview and http://data.worldbank.org/querybuilder :)

Comment: Great, that site is new to me. I will try it.
But I wonder why has everone different statistics?
E.g. Australias population:
CIA World FactBook: 22,262,501 (July 2013 est.) - 
World Databank: 22,683,600 (2012) - 
Wikipedia: 23.130.900 (Juni 2013)

Ok different timestamps but they vary between 400.000 and 500.000.
That is a huge variation.

The only benefit from the CIA World Factbook is that they have actual data and that's why I hope to get my information from this site.

Comment: [user15523956](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15523956) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66891468) saying "High quality of factbook data scrapping here: [https://github.com/Podipan/cia_world_factbook](https://github.com/Podipan/cia_world_factbook)"

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you're still looking, but there's a [JSON wrapper](https://github.com/opendatajson/factbook.json) on github now. You can query it like any old API.